# How to get pdf data in pdfkit without saving it to file

Tags: node.js, pdfkit, node-pdfkit

I am using pdfkit in nodejs to create pdfs. Right now, to get the data from pdfDocument, I first write it to a file using 'fs' and then read back from it.

I want to be able to use the data directly from pdfDocument object and send it as a response. How can I do that?

Comment: Which pdfkit? Ruby one or nodejs one? you have tagged them both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each pdfDocument is a stream. You can basically pipe it to the response like this:

```
require('http').createserver(function (request, response) {
    var pdfdocument = require('pdfkit'),
        pdfdocument = new pdfdocument();

    pdfdocument.text('wassup');
    pdfdocument.pipe(response);

    pdfdocument.end()
}).listen(1999);
```

Comment: I want to be able to post the pdfDocument as a response object. But I am unable to pipe the pdfDocument to a stream. How can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean by unable to pipe the pdfDocument to a stream? What's wrong with the code above? I tried it. It works.

Comment: @FaridNouriNeshat thanks. I wanted to ask if above can work with any other http handlers? your solution requires a port, I already have a hapi nodejs server and I am trying to replicate above with lambda function. which need to pass the response back to frontend website as a pdf download.

Comment: Yes, as long you have a response object or writable stream, otherwise you can just buffer it and return that as a result but I don't suggest that because it'd be slower.